# How to make Bootstrap Modal dialog responsive on a real iPhone if it already works on an emulated iPhone on Google Chrome?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I tried to make Bootstrap Modal box work and make it responsive, and read this question too: [Bootstrap Modal Dialog. Can the grid system be used within a modal context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204315/bootstrap-modal-dialog-can-the-grid-system-be-used-within-a-modal-context)

However, the page worked well in Google Chrome, and worked well in Google Chrome *simulated* iPhone 5, 6, or 6 Plus (note: as simulated in developer tool) -- but not work on a real iPhone 6 Plus or iPad (in the portrait mode). (the text appears really huge).

Is there a way to make it work?

The code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="col-md-4">
                1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p class="col-md-4">
                2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p class="col-md-4">
                3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sample page on: http://skiesof.blue/try/

**P.S.** I am looking into this issue further. With my iPhone 6 Plus that has iOS 9.3.1, it seems to work well, but on an iPad with iOS 9.0 or 9.1, it has this when the modal is popped up:

[image]

Comment: In my experience Google Chrome is VERY tolerant of code that wouldn't normally work in another browser (Safari, IE etc.). Have you tested/debugged in a different browser on your MacBook? I have to debug using IE which is more picky.

Comment: interesting to know of using IE so that it is less tolerating.  Is it IE 11 or Edge?  So do they have an emulation mode or you just resize the window so that it is not wide?

Comment: I use IE 11 but change the emulation to test back to IE9 (not earlier). There is emulation for iPad but not specifically iPhone - I usually just resize the screen or use a specific iPhone emulator like mobiletest.me or something. There are lots of options. Hope you get it working :)

Comment: try-fluid is the only one working correctly in FF.

Comment: hm... the other 2 files work except in 1 resolution? (1 width at about 750 to 992px)

Comment: What if you remove col-md-12? I think container should stand on its own. (Yes to the other question about the resolution).

Comment: Actually there is a pretty simple explanation why one works and the other two don't: For those who don't work your columns don't add up to 12, but to 9, if you change it to col-md-4 it would probably work for the others too.

Comment: but what about that it works on Google Chrome emulated iPhone, but not on the real iPhone?

Comment: have a look bootstrap example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-grid-system

Comment: no need this (<div class="container col-md-12"> </div>) div

Comment: have a look here http://www.bootply.com/Nn97PFniCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is an iOS9 issue and it's unrelated to the content of the modal. I haven't got an iPhone 6+ but I experienced the same issue on my iPad.
Adding the following CSS made it work for me:

```
body {
  padding-right: 0px !important
}

.modal-open {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720590/1581477

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/64#issuecomment-55794181

Comment: The solution actually require this answer and can be improved by the other answer by @Ismail.  There is some observations: (1) if the iOS is 9.3.1, then the 3 pages more or less work as they are... the issue is when it is iOS 9.0 or 9.1 (I am not sure about 9.2 and 9.3), and (2) adding `.modal-open` alone will fix the issue, it seemed (no need to use the `body` style), and make sure it is after linking to the `bootstrap.css` [cont'd...]

Comment: and (3) with the `.modal-open`, then the `try-simple.html` and `try-container.html` will overflow in the x-direction, and removing `<div class="container">` (and the closing `</div>`) as in @Ismail's answer will make it not overflow

Answer (score 2):

According to [bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-grid-system) there is no need to add `container col-md-12` after `modal-body` just add your html after `modal-body`.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>1st col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>2nd col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>3rd col 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>4th col 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```